# dispatch action after state change inside useEffect

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

i want to dispatch an action after state Change
in an useEffect

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrTime(activeCallTime());
      /**
       @todo:dispatch currtime action  
      **/
    }, 1000);
    
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [props.startTime]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    let timer = setInterval(() => {
     let temp = activeCallTime() 
     setCurrTime(temp);
      //dispatch temp
    }, 1000);
    
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [props.startTime]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        let timer = setInterval(() => {
          setCurrTime(activeCallTime());
        }, 1000);
        
        return () => clearInterval(timer);
      }, [props.startTime]); 

React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch the action  
 }, [currTime]);
```

Comment: That did not solve the issue

Comment: Sorry my bad, i updated the code